# Search worksheet for three names

Tags: vba, excel

Instead of looking for a number greater than 6 and sending it to another sheet. I want to look up 3 names so I can search a contact list and have it pull their information from the sheet to the report sheet.

below is my old code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, myCounter
Dim erow, myValue As Long

For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Range("C3").Value > 6 Then
        myCounter = 1
        ws.Select
        ws.Range("c3").Select

        myValue = ws.Range("C3").Value
        Worksheets("Report").Select
        erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1) = myValue

        nextValue = MsgBox("Value found in " & ws.Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?", vbInformation + vbYesvbNo, ws.Name & " C3 = " & ws.Range("C3").Value)
        Select Case nextValue
            Case Is = vbYes
            Case Is = vbNo
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End If
Next ws

If myCounter = 0 Then
    MsgBox "None of the sheets contains a " & Chr(10) & "value greater than 6 in cell C3 ", vbInformation, "Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

I think the third row should be `String` instead of `Long`.

The names I'm looking for are "David" "Andrea" & "Caroline", not sure if I write it three times or use a loop. Also I can't figure out how to search in the entire spreadsheet for these names.

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder and use the Find dialogue to find the names.  Stop recording and examine your code.  Put the names you want to find in 3 cells on a separate sheet and create a named range for those 3 cells called "NamesToFind".  With Sheet("Your sheet name").UsedRange set up a For Each Name in Range(NamesToFind) loop to use the Range.Find method to find the names.  Come back to us with the code when it doesn't work.  NB: the code you have is not a good starting point.

Comment: @VBABeginner  read my answer and code below, let me know if it works as you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will look for the names "David", "Andrea" and "Caroline" in cell "C3" in all of the worksheets. For every match it will copy it to the first empty row in Column A in "Report" worksheet.

**Note**: There is no need to use `Select` and `ActiveSheet`, instead use fully qualifed `Cells` and `Worksheets`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, myCounter As Long
Dim erow As Long, myValue As Long
Dim nextValue As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        Select Case .Range("C3").Value
            Case "David", "Andrea", "Caroline"
                myCounter = 1 ' raise flag >> found in at least 1 sheet

                ' get first empty row in "Report" sheet
                erow = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 1) = .Range("C3").Value

                nextValue = MsgBox("Value found in " & .Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, .Name & " C3 = " & .Range("C3").Value)
                Select Case nextValue
                    Case Is = vbYes ' <-- if you are not doing anything here, you don't need it >> maybe you don't need the entire `Select Case` here
                    Case Is = vbNo
                        Exit Sub
                End Select
        End Select ' Select Case .Range("C3").Value
    End With
Next ws

If myCounter = 0 Then
    MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & " 'David', 'Andrea', 'Caroline' in cell C3 ", vbInformation, "Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

---

**Comment**: It seems you are not doing anything in the case of `Case Is = vbYes` in the `Select Case` below:

```
nextValue = MsgBox("Value found in " & .Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, .Name & " C3 = " & .Range("C3").Value)
Select Case nextValue
    Case Is = vbYes ' <-- if you are not doing anything here, you don't need it >> maybe you don't need the entire `Select Case` here
    Case Is = vbNo
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

You can replace the entire thing with :

```
If MsgBox("Value found in " & .Name & Chr(10) & "Continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, .Name & " C3 = " & .Range("C3").Value) = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. How is it still "long" and not "string"

Comment: @VBABeginner what is `Long` ?

Comment: I just began learning so I might be wrong, but i thought Long was for numbers and string was for text. This code still works so it's throwing me off. However, I'm breaking my head trying to figure where I can tell it to search in "A1:E30" instead of "C3" in the sheets.

Comment: Oh yeah you have! thanks. I think Im going to go through other questions and see if I can answer some before I come back with mine. But dude thanks whoever you are.