# Changing the search from one cell to the entire sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried changing everywhere there was a cell to a range and other things but I can't figure it out. I'd like for the code to search the entire sheet, instead of one cell, for these names and paste the information of the cell to the right of it to the other sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, myCounter As Long
Dim erow As Long, myValue As Long
Dim nextValue As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
With ws
    Select Case .Range("C3").Value
        Case "David", "Andrea", "Caroline"
            myCounter = 1 ' raise flag >> found in at least 1 sheet

            ' get first empty row in "Report" sheet
            erow = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 1) = .Range("C3").Value

    End Select ' Select Case .Range("C3").Value
End With
Next ws

If myCounter = 0 Then
MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & " 'David', 'Andrea', 'Caroline' in cell C3 ", vbInformation, "Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to look in a single (or possibly multiple) column(s), single (or possibly multiple) row(s) or literally every cell on the worksheet?

Comment: @Jeeped see former post for his `Range` , it's in his comments to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879800/changed-mind-and-code/42887769#42887769

Comment: Btw, @vbabeginner - Please read the attached comment to the `[macro]` tag (just hover over it). It is explicitly **not** to be used for VBA sub procedures.

Comment: @Jeeped - Oops - I just deleted the tag before seeing your comment telling the OP to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Application.Match` with array version. Substitute this for your loop:

```
Dim ar, r
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ar = Application.match(Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline"), ws.Columns("C"), 0)
    For Each r In ar
        If Not IsError(r) Then
            myCounter = 1 ' raise flag >> found in at least 1 sheet
            erow = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 1) = ws.Range("C" & r).value
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 2) = ws.Range("D" & r).value
        End If
    Next r
Next ws
```

Notice though, that this will find you only one match for each word, the first one. If each word can be repeated many times and you want to find all matches, it will need some modification.

Comment: Nice :) However stealing the `Match` from me? this is my bread and butter ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado lol I've taken a look at your other answer, it doesn't use `Match` :P

Comment: There was no need to, since he was looking at a single cell.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tweaked it to this:

Comment: For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ar = Application.Match(Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline"), ws.Columns("C"), 0)
    For Each r In ar
        If Not IsError(r) Then
            myCounter = 1 ' raise flag >> found in at least 1 sheet
            erow = Worksheets("Report").Cells(Worksheets("Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 1) = ws.Range("A" & r).Value
            Worksheets("Report").Cells(erow, 2) = ws.Range("B" & r).Value

Comment: Why does changing the columns from A to C in the "application.match" line change the output?

Comment: @VBABeginner You surely need to tweak it somehow, feel free as Code on SO is not copyrighted :P. Glad to help, you're welcome.

Comment: @VBABeginner because it specifies the column in which you want to match the provided keywords. If you change it, the result changes because data in the columns is different.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple rows and multiple columns would be better served by the Find command.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, bFound As Boolean, rFound As Range
    Dim a As Long, aNames As Variant

    aNames = Array("David", "Andrea", "Caroline")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'If ws.Name <> Worksheets("Report").Name Then
        If ws.Name = "Sheet7" Then
            With ws.Range("A1:E30").Cells
                For a = LBound(aNames) To UBound(aNames)
                    Set rFound = .Find(What:=aNames(a), MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False)
                    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                        bFound = True
                        With Worksheets("Report")
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = rFound.Value
                        End With
                    End If
                Next a
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    If Not bFound Then
        MsgBox "None of the sheets contains the names " & Chr(10) & _
            "'" & Join(aNames, "', '") & "' in cells A1:E30.", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Both of these are perfect. This second one does grab the information from the cell next to it, but i think this one might be better. How come I can't vote for both?

Comment: There is only supposed to be one answer per question but upvotes reflect the quality of other appropriate responses.

Comment: @VBABeginner - Changing `rFound.Value` to `rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value` would retrieve the value from one column to the left.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped and everyone. I will go back now and toggle with every line and see if i can learn from this.